# Deciphering the key

Tags: algorithm

Alice invents a key (s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, s<sub>3</sub>, ... , s<sub>k</sub>). Bob makes a guess (g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, g<sub>3</sub>, ... , g<sub>k</sub>).He is awarded one point for each s<sub>i</sub> = g<sub>i</sub>. 
Each s1 is an integer with the range of 0<=s<sub>i</sub><=11.
Given a q guesses with their scores b<sub>i</sub>
 
(g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, g<sub>3</sub>, ... , g<sub>k</sub>) b<sub>1</sub>
(g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, g<sub>3</sub>, ... , g<sub>k</sub>) b<sub>2</sub>
.
.
.
(g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, g<sub>3</sub>, ... , g<sub>k</sub>) b<sub>q</sub>

Can you state if there is a key possible.  Given 0<=si<=11, 1<=k<=11, 1<=q<=8.
For Example
2 2 1 1 2
1 1 2 2 1 

For the guess 2 2 1 1 the score is 2
For the guess 1 1 2 2 the score is 1
Because there is a key possible let's say 2 1 1 3 which gives the desired scores.Hence the answer is yes

Another Example
1 2 3 4 4
4 3 2 1 1

For the guess 1 2 3 4 the score is 4
For the guess 4 3 2 1 the score is 1

This has no key which gives the desired scores hence answer is NO

I tried the brute force approach generating n^k such keys where n is the range of s<sub>i</sub>.But it gave Time Limit exceeding error.
Its an interview puzzle. I have seen variants of this question but was not able to solve them.Can you tell me what should I read for such type of questions.

Comment: I'm assuming you're saying the key and guesses are 11 characters long, and you can have 8 guesses.  But without knowing the alphabet (what each character *can* be), it's impossible to say whether or not it's possible in 8 guesses.

Comment: @bdares:  I *think* he means that the alphabet consists of the integers 0 to 11 (12 possible values for each s) by the "0<=si<=11" statement.  But I may not be interpreting it correctly.

Comment: @bdares I hope this edition clears the ambiguity in the question.

Comment: I have added examples to remove any ambiguity if there was one before.Please open the question as I do not seek the exact solution but the concept on which such questions are based

Comment: your examples are not clear . what you gave are guesses.. shouldnt there be scored to them that were  given ? without the scores how can we solve this,?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the best solution to this problem, but if you did a recursive search of the possible solution space, pruning branches which could not possibly lead to a solution, it would be much faster than trying all (n^k) keys.

Take your example:

1 2 3 4 4 -> 4
4 3 2 1 1 -> 1

The 3 possible values for g1 which could be significant are: 1, 4, and "neither 1 nor 4". Choose one of them, and then recursively look at the possible values for g2. Choose one, and recursively look at the possible values for g3, etc.

As you search, keep track of a cumulative score for each of the guesses from b1 to bq. Whenever you choose a value for a digit, increment the cumulative scores for all the guesses which have the same number in that position. Keep these cumulative scores on a stack (so you can back up).

When you reach a point where no solution is possible, back up and continue searching a different path. If you back all the way up to g1 and no more paths are left to search, then the answer is NO. If you find a solution, then the answer is YES.

When to stop searching a path and back up:

- If the cumulative score of one of the guesses exceeds the given score
- If the cumulative score of one of the guesses is less than the given score minus the number of levels left in the search tree (before you hit the bottom)

This approach could still be very slow, especially if "k" was large. But again, it will be far faster than generating (n^k) keys.